# How to query unique documents for a given field where there is a referenced 1-N relationship in Mongoid?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_many :foos
end

class Foo
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :group_id, type:String

  belongs_to :user
end
```

Each Foo belongs to a group with a group_id. However, there is no Group model.

What is an efficient way to get the single latest (highest created_at) Foo for each group_id?